# adding the wmic bios get serialnumber to script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following script

```
set ip_address_string="IPv4 Address"
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:%ip_address_string%`) do (
@(Echo Status,Date,Time,Device,User,IP,SN & Echo Logon,%DATE%,%TIME%,%COMPUTERNAME%,%USERNAME%,%%f,%SerialNumber%))1>%RANDOM%.csv
goto :eof
```

The script works great but I need to capture the PC serialnumber within my script, for eg

```
for /F %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber') do call :Sub %%a
echo The serial number is %SerialNumber%
:Sub
if not "%*"=="" set SerialNumber=%*
```

So I can get the following "Logon,14/06/2021,22:03:18.28,LT6880,Testuser,192.168.0.46,B4Q4MN3"

but so far its been unsuccessful, can someone please point me in the correct direction?

Many Thanks

John

Comment: seems to work fine on my computer. Please describe "unsuccessful"

Comment: Put `goto :EOF` before `:SUB`…

Comment: Hi , cant seem to add ,%SerialNumber% to the end of the script, looking to add the 2 scripts together to achieve the following output "Logon,14/06/2021,22:03:18.28,LT6880,Testuser,192.168.0.46,B4Q4MN3" - but not sure on how to merge the two together to achieve this? any help would be greatly apprcaited.  Thanks

Comment: You `echo Logon, .....,%serialnumber%`, so `%serialnumber%` should exist at that time. That makes it clear, where to put the code to get the serialnumber: *before* echoing it.